# BroadCast Receiver Android FireBase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a badge on my bottom navigation bar, and I have specific Child in My FireStore database, I want in every data change I want to increment badger number, 
Here is my pseudo code for retrieving Child value.

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Jobs").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            int count = 0;
            jobList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                count++;
                Log.d("idddddd", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData().get("CreationDate"));
                JobsData data = document.toObject(JobsData.class);
                jobList.add(data);
                Log.d("idddddd", String.valueOf(count));
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the exact data you want to get and the exact data you want to increment.

Comment: Thanks but It's not the problem of data that i want to retrieve, i'm suck how to implement broadcast receiver that can detect data change from firestore